# Изменение данных типа double в ячейке DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf, mvvm

Всем привет!

Есть DataGrid, к которому привязан контейнер данных, в столбцы я вывожу данные типа double, с возможностью их редактирования. Выводить нужно в формате 4 знака после запятой. После редактирования ячейки пользователем (столбец Цена) необходимо проверить, что введенное число больше нуля, округлить его до 4-х знаков после запятой и вывести в ячейку, и изменить содержимое другой ячейки, в зависимости от значения данной. Я использую MVVM модель.

Проблема состоит в том, как получить введенное значение, чтобы его валидировать, округлить. К SelectedItem у меня привязка есть. Но когда вызывается команда ChangeCellCommand там хранится ещё старое значение. Может, ещё какая-то команда есть после завершения редактирования?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="50,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeCellCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=CurrentCell , ElementName=DataGrid}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="BeginningEdit">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding BeginningEditCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена"            FontFamily="Arial" Binding="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay}"   Width="*" MinWidth="80" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество"  FontFamily="Arial" Binding="{Binding Number}"  Width="*" MinWidth="120"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используете MVVM, то имеет смысл валидировать источник данных. Предполагаю, что ваш код похож на следующий (самом собой, модели представления реализуют INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
class SomeProductVm : ViewModel
{
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}

class MainVm : ViewModel
{
    public SomeProduct SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Этот код нужно будет дополнить следующим образом:

```
// добавляем реализацию IDataErrorInfo в базовую модель представления
class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return Validate(propertyName); }
    }

    private string Validate(string propertyName)
    {
        var value = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = propertyName };

        if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, context, results))
        {
            return results.First().ErrorMessage;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}


static class SomeProductValidator
{
    // добавляем метод валидации для свойства SomeProduct.Cost
    public static ValidationResult ValidateCost(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var someProduct = (SomeProductVm) context.ObjectInstance;
        if (someProduct < 0)
            return new ValidationResult("Цена должна быть больше нуля");
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

class SomeProductVm : ViewModel
{
    // вешаем атрибут на свойство
    [CustomValidation(typeof(SomeProductValidator), "ValidateCost")]
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и не забываем доработать XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" .../>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем я вас понял, если честно. В любом случае, это похоже на то, что решает такой принцип ООП, как инкапсуляции.
А вообще-то, у вас тут сразу несколько задач, которые было бы неплохо разбить на более мелкие

1. Нужно выводить числа в заданном формате - *Это клссическая задача на инкапсуляцию. Храним и обрабатываем double, выводим string.*
2. Необходимо произвести валидацию данных, соблюдая шаблон MVVM - *Почитайте про валидацию используя аттрибуты и интерфейс IDataErrorInfo - вот хорошая статья http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784331/WPF-MVVM-Validation-ViewModel-using-IDataErrorInfo*
3. Нужно между собой связать значения двух ячеек - *Здесь всё сложнее, ибо вам нужно понимать, паттерн MVVM придуман, что-бы избежать редактирования ячеек напрямую, поэтому здесь вам может помочь реализация логики в вашем ViewModel'e по реакции на событие OnPropertyChanged вашей коллекции*

И немного критики - старайтесь избегать триггеров. Ведь по сути это те-же обработчики событий - события, которые срабатывают в UI, а обрабатываются в коде. Вашу задачу можно решить проще и красивее. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Double">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="Value" StringFormat="0.0000">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <!-- Тут можно указать значения Max и Min -->
                <local:ValueRule Min="0"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

local: - это пространство имен, в котором расположен валидатор (см ниже). Обратите внимание еще на StringFormat="0.0000", который говорит, что у нас 4 знака после запятой

А вот само правило валидации

```
public class ValueRule : ValidationRule
{
    private double min = 0;
    private double max = Double.MaxValue;

    public double Min
    {
        get { return min; }
        set { min = value; }
    }

    public double Max
    {
        get { return max; }
        set { max = value; }
    }


    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci)
    {
        double price = 0;

        try
        {
            price = Double.Parse((string)value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Недопустимые символы.");
        }

        if ((price < Min) || (price > Max))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,
              "Стоимость не входит в диапазон " + Min + " до " + Max + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```